# How does Android Chrome send newline from soft keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, chrome-for-android, special-chars

I am attempting to access an ESP32 microcontroller running MicroPython over a web interface using the following page [WebREPL](http://micropython.org/webrepl/) which within my local network using Chrome on my PC is all fine.

The problem arises when I use the same page from my Android using Chrome and attempt to input the password, followed by the 'enter' key which is promptly rejected as the wrong password - the password I have configured uses only upper and lowercase with no symbols so the only way I can see things getting FUBAR is with the line ending being sent.

Can anybody shed some knowledge on what ascii or whatever code the keyboard would be sending back through the connection, or if there is any possibility there is a space being appended first (the web page does not echo the password keys being entered) - also are there any apps or hacks to give more transparency to what the keyboard is sending in general for non alphanumeric characters?

Comment: [Key event list](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) may help

Comment: I assume this is more a problem of the WebREPL web page you use. Because the keyboard only sends standard key events, what the web page creates from the key event is the question. Try to use telnet on your PC (on Windows it can be installed in Windows options) for connecting to your microcontroller. On Android side a telnet app would also be my preferred preference.

Comment: There's the rub,trying to be a good netizen and figure out what the problem with WebREPL could be in order to send a more useful bug report up stream - definitely wherever the bug lies it will need to be fixed there. Meanwhile I do not see any way that WebREPL (from what I have groked which is not all) would be treating the character streams between the two differently unless they actually are: which I'm at a loss to test... Will definitely give Telnet client on the Android side a try as a workaround and possibly as a tool to illuminate what Chrome is sending. Thanks for the suggestion!